# What am I misunderstanding about Rx.observable.take()

Tags: angular, rxjs

Im still learning through some experiments how to use Angular5 with rxjs, and I ran into something I struggled to understand.

How do I return only part of the results from an Observable using [Rx.Observable.take(count)](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html)

I found an API that returns 500 array items
at: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments

I set up an angular service called rxservice that uses `HttpClient.get()` to return an observable like this:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
    import { map,take } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Http } from "@angular/http";
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

    @Injectable()
    export class RxService {

    constructor(
      private http: HttpClient) { }  

      getComments():Observable<any>{
        this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments").take(42).subscribe(whyNotArrayof42 => console.log(whyNotArrayof42)); 
        return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments").take(42); // <=== Returns an observable, but when I subscribe in the component, gives me all 500 array items.          
      }
    }
```

In the component I call the service as follows:

```
getFromService() {
    this.rxservice.getComments()
    .subscribe(notAtTheComponentEither => console.log(notAtTheComponentEither));
  }
```

The console spits out two arrays with 500 objects each. I expected that the .take(42) would filter out only the 42 first items of the array. But it does not. What am I misunderstanding? Can someone point me in the right direction?

I know I could just splice the array when I get it back, but I thought the idea behind `.take(count)` was to limit how much is loaded from the API. If the array was of size millions it seems to make sense to divide it into smaller chunks with `.take(count)` wouldn't it?

Comment: `take` takes the first `n` arrays, it doesn't touch the contents of the messages.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I am pretty sure `take` applies to events. Therefore, if you have `take(3)`, it would run the code you want for the first three times that event was called. I could for sure be wrong about that...

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing `take()` with paging operators and arrays in general.  The `take(n)` operator will complete after `n` emits of observable data.

It is not some magic function that knows how to limit the amount of data coming back from your API.  You need to explicitly tell your API how much data you want.

In your example the entire array is the observable data, not each element of the array.  With the entire array being emitted each time it will stop doing so after the 42nd emit i.e. your subscribe function would not be called.

You can implement paging either client side (with relatively small data sets) or server side (with larger data sets) but observables are not the data structure for this.